# opencv program crashes only when debugger is attached

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <direct.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "vfw32.lib")
#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib" )
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void PrintFullPath(char * partialPath)
{
    char full[_MAX_PATH];
    if (_fullpath(full, partialPath, _MAX_PATH) != NULL)
        printf("Full path is: %s\n", full);
    else
        printf("Invalid path\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    PrintFullPath(".\\");
    Mat edges;
    VideoCapture cap;
    try
    {
        cap.open(0); // open the default camera
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "error!!" << endl;
    }
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    //Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges", 1);
    for (;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        edges = frame;
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7, 7), 1.5, 1.5);
        //Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        //Sleep(2000);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the program crashes ONLY when the debugger is attached, when i press f5 it crashes in line "cap.open(0)", but when I press cntrol f5 it runs perfectly.

the error i get is:

Unhandled exception at 0x09068EFB in opencv_1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x09068EFB.

im using visual studio 2013, windows 8.0, opencv 3.0.

if i run the exe file in the command line the prorgam runs perfectly.

Comment: Are you linking to the debug libraries in the vc12 folder of the binary download? This problem could be caused by linking to the wrong binaries.

Comment: i think so, i followed the instructions, how can i know for sure?

Comment: Check the program properties (in VS 2012 it's Debug > Program Properties), then take a look at the Config Properties > Linker > Input > additional dependencies.  Make sure for the Debug config all of the libraries are opencv_xxxd.lib. I also had to have the Runtime Library (Config Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation) set to /MTd